# Open ports for p2p chat

Tags: c#, visual-studio, port, p2p, firewall

I want to write a p2p chat program using server in c#.
Basically, when client A would want to send a message to client B,
the server will notify client B for the request, and open
port and create socket. The messages will transfer directly from
one clint to the other.

The Question:
How can i open port on the firewall and save it in the NAT?
Is there any c# code for that (open source)?

Comment: Does this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231058-peer-to-peer-chat-advanced/ help?

Comment: No. This code relevant for p2p chat in the local area network.